# Delete first element from each array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a multi dimensional array like this.

```
 var myArray = [['aaa','1','2.33','44'],['bbb','1','2.33','44'],['ccc','1','2.33','44']]
```

I want to remove all the first element to get a result like this.

```
var myArray = [['1','2.33','44'],['1','2.33','44'],['1','2.33','44']]
```

Please Help me. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```js
var myArray = [['aaa','1','2.33','44'],['bbb','1','2.33','44'],['ccc','1','2.33','44']];
var done = function(){
  console.log(myArray);
};
myArray.forEach(function(array){
  array.splice(0,1);
  done();
});
```

Output

```
[['1','2.33','44'],['1','2.33','44'],['1','2.33','44']];
```

Answer (score 9):

Use **[.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** to loop over the nested arrays and then **[.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** them. Splice will remove the first item in the nested array and effect the current array.

```js
var myArray = [['aaa','1','2.33','44'],['bbb','1','2.33','44'],['ccc','1','2.33','44']];

myArray.forEach(array => array.splice(0,1));

console.log(myArray);
```

Base on the comment you can also use [**.shift()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) function to remove the first item.

```js
var myArray = [['aaa','1','2.33','44'],['bbb','1','2.33','44'],['ccc','1','2.33','44']];

myArray.forEach(array => array.shift());

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: You can also use `.shift()` instead of `.splice(0,1)`.