# Remove first item of array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

How do I remove 1 and 3 from below array in array?

```
[[1,2], [3,4,5]]

[[2],[4,5]]
```

was thinking about pop() but stuck somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete first element from each array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674164/delete-first-element-from-each-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use JavaScript built-in function `shift()`.

```
var a = [[1,2], [3,4,5]];

a.map(item => { 
    item.shift();
    return item;
});

console.log(a); // [[2], [4, 5]]
```

Official guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
const a = [[1,2], [3,4,5]];

console.log(
  a.map(item => item.splice(1))
)
```

Basically you're mapping each item of the array with the same array without the first element (since `splice` mutate the array).

If you want have a *copy* also of the inner array, then you should use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the main array as you normally would, like

```
    let array = [[1,2], [3,4,5]]
    for (let el of array) {
         // Now you'll be accessing each array inside the main array,
         // YOu can now remove the first element using .shift()
         el.shift();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the array, and got all items, but the the 1st, with `Array.slice()`:

```js
const arr = [[1,2], [3,4,5]];

const result = arr.map(item => item.slice(1));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var arr = [[1,2], [3,4,5]];

for (var innerArray of arr) {
  // Using array.splice()
  for (var element of innerArray) {
   if (element === 1 || element === 3) innerArray.splice(innerArray.indexOf(element), 1);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```